# Sublime text regex find/replace not recognising regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, find-replace

I have to find/replace A LOT of inputs in a lot of files that have name and are either required or have minlength/maxlength or ng-pattern attribute.

I made this regex:

```
<input([^\/\>]*?) name="([\S\_]+?)" ([^\/\>]*?)(required|pattern|minlength|maxlength)([^\/\>]*?)\/\>
```

I tested this regex on regex101.com (as a js regex though) and it works.
Sublime probably has slightly different regex syntax than javascript, but I've been using regex find/replace a lot recently, and this is the first time it's not working.

I'm pretty sure it's these parts that are problematic:

```
([^\/\>]*?)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<` and `>` don't need to be escaped. So don't escape your the last character i.e change `\>` to `>`

```
<input([^\/\>]*?) name="([\S\_]+?)" ([^\/\>]*?)
(required|pattern|minlength|maxlength)([^\/\>]*?)\/>
                                                   ^ Don't escape
```

instead of

```
<input([^\/\>]*?) name="([\S\_]+?)" ([^\/\>]*?)
(required|pattern|minlength|maxlength)([^\/\>]*?)\/\>
                                                   ^ Doesn't WORK in sublimetext
```